# Spring Integration tcp client multiple connections

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I use Spring Integration tcp-outbound-adapter and tcp-inbound-adapter in order to communicate with a third party external system through TCP.

The connection factory I use is of type "client" and has single-use="false", because the nature of communication with the external system is a session of several dozens requests and replies.
The external system expects I will open a new TCP connection for each session.

Is there any way to do that with Spring Integration?

My code uses SI successfully for one such session. But I want my system to open several such connections so I can handle several concurrent sessions.
Currently, if I send a message of a new session to the inbound adapter, it uses the same TCP connection.

Please help.

UPDATE:

While using the ThreadAffinity solution given by Gary here, we get this exception when we do more than 4 concurrent requests. Any idea why is that?

```
11:08:02.083  [pool-1-thread-2] 193.xxx.yyy.zz:443:55729:46c71372-5933-4707-a27b-93cc4bf78c59 Message sent GenericMessage [payload=byte[326], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2fb866, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2fb866, ip_tcp_remotePort=55718, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:55718:4444:7f71ce96-eaac-4b21-8b2c-bf736102f818, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=2dc3e330-d703-8a61-c46c-012233cadf6f, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1481706480700}]
11:08:12.093  [pool-1-thread-2] Remote Timeout on 193.xxx.yyy.zz:443:55729:46c71372-5933-4707-a27b-93cc4bf78c59
11:08:12.093  [pool-1-thread-2] Tcp Gateway exception
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response
            at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:146)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)
            at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
            at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:441)
            at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:409)
            at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.doOnMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:120)
            at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.onMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:98)
            at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport.onMessage(TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport.java:159)
            at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:182)
            at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport.run(TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport.java:111)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what constitutes a "session" - if all the requests from a session on the client side all run on a single thread, you could write a simple wrapper for the connection factory that stores the connection in a `ThreadLocal`. You would need some mechanism to call the factory wrapper after the last request to close the connection and remove it from the `ThreadLocal`.

If the requests for a session can occur on multiple threads, it would be a bit more complicated but you could still do it with a `ThreadLocal` that maps to a connection instance.

**EDIT**

Here's an example...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So40507731Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So40507731Application.class, args);
        MessageChannel channel = context.getBean("clientFlow.input", MessageChannel.class);
        MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate(channel);
        ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory affinityCF = context.getBean(ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory.class);
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        exec.execute(() -> {
            String result = new String(template.convertSendAndReceive("foo", byte[].class));
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + result);
            result = new String(template.convertSendAndReceive("foo", byte[].class));
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + result);
            affinityCF.release();
            latch.countDown();
        });
        exec.execute(() -> {
            String result = new String(template.convertSendAndReceive("foo", byte[].class));
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + result);
            result = new String(template.convertSendAndReceive("foo", byte[].class));
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + result);
            affinityCF.release();
            latch.countDown();
        });
        latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        context.close();
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory delegateCF() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientCF = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 1234);
        clientCF.setSingleUse(true); // so each thread gets his own connection
        return clientCF;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory affinityCF() {
        return new ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory(delegateCF());
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpOutboundGateway outGate() {
        TcpOutboundGateway outGate = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        outGate.setConnectionFactory(affinityCF());
        return outGate;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow clientFlow() {
        return f -> f.handle(outGate());
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverCF() {
        return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(1234);
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway inGate() {
        TcpInboundGateway inGate = new TcpInboundGateway();
        inGate.setConnectionFactory(serverCF());
        return inGate;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow serverFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inGate())
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .transform("headers['ip_connectionId'] + ' ' + payload")
                .get();
    }

    public static class ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory extends AbstractClientConnectionFactory
            implements TcpListener {

        private final AbstractClientConnectionFactory delegate;

        private final ThreadLocal<TcpConnectionSupport> connection = new ThreadLocal<>();

        public ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory(AbstractClientConnectionFactory delegate) {
            super("", 0);
            delegate.registerListener(this);
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        protected TcpConnectionSupport obtainConnection() throws Exception {
            TcpConnectionSupport tcpConnection = this.connection.get();
            if (tcpConnection == null || !tcpConnection.isOpen()) {
                tcpConnection = this.delegate.getConnection();
                this.connection.set(tcpConnection);
            }
            return tcpConnection;
        }

        public void release() {
            TcpConnectionSupport connection = this.connection.get();
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
                this.connection.remove();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void start() {
            this.delegate.start();
            setActive(true);
            super.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            this.delegate.stop();
            setActive(false);
            super.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMessage(Message<?> message) {
            return getListener().onMessage(message);
        }

    }

}
```

Result:

```
pool-2-thread-2 localhost:64559:1234:3d898822-ea91-421d-97f2-5f9620b9d369 foo
pool-2-thread-1 localhost:64560:1234:227f8a9f-1461-41bf-943c-68a56f708b0c foo
pool-2-thread-2 localhost:64559:1234:3d898822-ea91-421d-97f2-5f9620b9d369 foo
pool-2-thread-1 localhost:64560:1234:227f8a9f-1461-41bf-943c-68a56f708b0c foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Is it not a regular use-case for which there is already a prepared solution in SI?

Comment: I assume the wrapper would be similar to the CachingClientConnectionFactory ? But how do I configure the int-ip:tcp-connection-factory to return the wrapper class?

Comment: Could you please advise in more details how to do that? I have tried several possibilities and none of them works. It seems that the logic of having one shared connection (in case of singleUse="false") is found in many classes. TIA for any help.

Comment: It hasn't been asked for before; I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4166). It would use a similar technique to the caching CF but a lot less complex because it simply delegates and doesn't have to wrap the connection itself. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. It was very helpful. However, you used singleUse=true, and my use-case is different: I have several tcp clients (in the same JVM), all connecting to the same tcp server (an external system), and on each of them there is a "conversation" that contains 20-150 messages in both directions. So I must use singleUse=false and 2 channel adapters. I extended your code sample, but had to copy-paste the ConnectionFactoryFactoryBean to my own code, in order to create my own ConnectionFactory, because some of its methods can not be extended.

Comment: As you can see from my test, the same connection was used  twice each. `singleUse=true` was simply a fake out - it tells the underlying connection factory to create a new socket for each `getConnection()` call (when false, a single socket is shared). Since the `ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory` holds a reference to each connection so created, it can be used multiple times. The outbound endpoints use the `singleUse` property of the wrapping CF to determine whether or not to close the socket after each use. Since it is false, the connection is reused properly as required.

Comment: (The above comment applies if you are using 4.2 or higher).

Comment: I use 2 channel adapters (inbound and outbound), and not one gateway adapter as in your example. I see that each adapter runs in a separate thread. The thread that opens a connection to the TCP server puts the connection in the thread local, but the thread that receives the response from TCP Server does not have this connection in the thread local. Do you suggest that I work with a gateway like in your example?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference; you are just changing where the request/reply correlation is done and handing off the reply to the calling thread. I would use a gateway in this scenario so your code doesn't have to deal with such details. The only reason I can think of to not do that is if you want the calling thread to do some more work while awaiting the reply.

Comment: I have another issue and I am not sure if it is connected with this solution. I Updated my original question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Also - If I use Vrtx for TCP communication instead of the Spring Integration TCP adapters, will I get any advantage?

Comment: I can't speak to vrtx; your issue is because you are using independent channel adapters instead of a gateway; you need to show the rest of your flow but, if it begins with a gateway; you need to save off the replyChannel header somehow. This [sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex) shows one technique but it's generally easier to use gateways and let the framework do the correlation for you.

Comment: We use the ThreadAffinity solution as suggested here and it works great! However, when sending more than 4 concurrent requests we start getting exceptions. I updated the question to display this exception. Can you please help.

Comment: There is not enough information in a stack trace for something like that; you would need to turn on DEBUG logging to see what's happening. Given the length of the comments here, it would be better to start a new question if you can't figure out what's happening from the logs.