# Spring Integration tcp Server multiple connections

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How to write a wrapper for `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` below and turn it into a multithreaded connections pool?
There is an exmaple [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507731/spring-integration-tcp-client-multiple-connections/40509015#40509015) but it is for `TncpNetServerConnectionFactory`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So39290834Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So39290834Application.class, args);
        Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 9999);
        socket.getOutputStream().write("foo\r\n".getBytes());
        socket.close();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf() {
        return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(9999);
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inbound(AbstractServerConnectionFactory cf) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(tcpIn());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel tcpIn() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "tcpIn", outputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    @Bean
    public ObjectToStringTransformer transformer() {
        return new ObjectToStringTransformer();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    public void service(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```