# Spring Integration TCP Multiple sockets on client side to one server address

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration

Requisites:

- I should open multiple sockets/connections to the same server IP and
  Port.
- I should detect from which connection a request has come and
  reroute the response to the same connection
- A connection is represented as server Ip and port + client Ip and
  port
- Each connection has to be single-use=false, it is expected to have multiple request/replies

I'm using collaborating TcpReceivingChannelAdapter and TcpSendingMessageHandler with TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.

And IntegrationFlow for generating those connections dynamically.

---

How to create multiple sockets for TcpNetClientConnectionFactory that all point to the same Host and port?

I know how to set destination with new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port). But I'm unable to see or find how to affect which port is used

Should it be done with multiple TcpNetClientConnectionFactory each being bound to one inbound and outbound TCP adapter?

How can I set the local port for those connections? or at least how to obtain it?

I don't seem to find any documentantion about this option. The most similar would be [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507731/spring-integration-tcp-client-multiple-connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate connection factory/adapters for each.

See [TCP Connection Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events).

Use an `ApplicationListener` or `@EventListener` to receive `TcpConnectionEvent`s.

The event has `getConnectionId()` which contains both the local and remote port; the event also has the connection factory bean name.

Or you can cast `getSource()` to `TcpConnection` and call `getPort()` (but you should not otherwise interact with the `TcpConnection` object.

Comment: Yes , but what about the multiple sockets or how to set a sockets localhost port? I know it is possible with a serverconnection but in this case it is required we connect as clients. is the approach of creating multiple connection factories correct then?

Comment: Yes; you need multiple factories, as I said in the answer. It is not currently possible to specify the local port with standard components; the OS chooses a free one. A work around would be to inject your own implementation of `TcpSocketFactorySupport` into the `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory`. The implementation would have to return a custom socket factory that delegates to a method that allows specification of the local port when `createSocket(host, port)` is called by the connection factory. Feel free to [open a new feature request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and response